# Why can't I authenticate to Facebook Chat in my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I have been scouring the internet trying to find a solution to this problem.  I understand the basic idea on how it is supposed to work, but I can't get the implementation to work and I can't find any decent examples to help me.  So far I have successfully been able to log in a user using the iOS 6 authentication mechanism, but I cannot figure out how to authenticate a user to the Jabber server from there.  Here is what I have:

After the user has logged in `connect` is called

```
-(void)connect
{
    [self setupStream];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [_xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken: FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self];
}

-(void)newSetupStream
{
    _xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] initWithFacebookAppId:@"611051652253156"];

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
{
    xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
}
#endif


    _xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];


    _xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];

    _xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:_xmppRosterStorage];
    _xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
    _xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;


    _xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    _xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:_xmppvCardStorage];
    _xmppvCardAvatarModule = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc] initWithvCardTempModule:_xmppvCardTempModule];


    _xmppCapabilitiesStorage = [XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    _xmppCapabilities = [[XMPPCapabilities alloc] initWithCapabilitiesStorage:_xmppCapabilitiesStorage];
    _xmppCapabilities.autoFetchHashedCapabilities = YES;
    _xmppCapabilities.autoFetchNonHashedCapabilities = NO;


    [_xmppReconnect         activate:_xmppStream];
    [_xmppRoster            activate:_xmppStream];
    [_xmppvCardTempModule   activate:_xmppStream];
    [_xmppvCardAvatarModule activate:_xmppStream];
    [_xmppCapabilities      activate:_xmppStream];


    [_xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

No matter what I try it always returns the same error: `Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=4 "The server does not support X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication."`

I am not incredibly familiar with either XMPP or the Facebook API so I'm sure there is something simple I am missing, but I have been working on this forever and been unable to make any progress.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.  In case anyone else runs into this same problem: I never actually told my XMPPStream to connect.  I had tried all of the connect methods before, but they never worked.  I now realize that I simply did not wait for them to finish connecting.  Here is what I ended up changing:

```
NSError *error;
NSError *err;
[_xmppStream connectWithTimeout:10.00 error:&err];

[_xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken: FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken error:&error];
while (error)
{
    sleep(1);
    [_xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken: FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken error:&error];
}
```

I realize that it's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use chat.facebook.com or facebook.com as the host name.

You must also open session with **xmpp_login** permission.

For me the above host name worked 100% fine